# Android ListView - Making the parent expand to show all children when addingListViews within ListViews

Tags: android, listview, parent-child

Basically, I have a custom ListView in which each item looks like:

`<LinearLayout>`

`<Table> <Row> <TextView/> <Button /> </Row> </Table>`

`<ListView />`

`</LinearLayout>`

The ListView in each item is GONE by default and is set to VISIBLE when the button is clicked.  Everything seems to work fine with the exception that when the ListView is long enough to scroll, it is just kind of truncated.

http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/3269/listviewproblem.png

Is this a problem with the maximum height of an individual list item? Is there a way to force the list item to expand and force the child listview to expand to show all children?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show your ListView setup?

Comment: I ended up giving up and writing my own class.

Comment: I am interested in knowing how you managed to create the user interface. Would you mind sharing? You can send me an email at [samikr@orworks.net]. Thanks.

Comment: Would love to see your solution, please post it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use seperate relative layout for listitem

set the layout in list activity with the help of custom efficientadapter.

thats all.